# Count the cells

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a multi-line string as input containing characters `"|"`, `"_"` and `" "` (space), count the number of cells it contains.

A cell is the following structure of 3 characters by 2 lines:

```
 _
|_|
```

That is, an underscore on one line (the characters to its right and left don’t matter), and `"|_|"` right below it.

Two cells can share the same characters. For example, there are 3 cells here:

```
 _
|_|_
|_|_|
```

#### Inputs and outputs

- You can assume that the input string will only contain the following characters: `"|"`, `"_"`, `" "`, and `"\n"`.
- You may take a list of strings as input, or a list of lists of chars, instead of a multi-line string.
- You may assume that there are at least 2 lines and 3 chars per line.
- You may pad each line with spaces so that all lines have the same length.

#### Test cases

```
Input                               Output

 _
|_|                                 1

___
|_|                                 1

   
|_|                                 0

 _  _  __ __
|_|  _|  _|_||                      2


 _
|_|_
|_|_|                               3

 _
| |_
|_|_|                               1

 _
|_|_
|___|                               1

 _ _
|_|_|
|_|_|                               4
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we assume the input has at least 2 rows and 3 columns?

Comment: @Adám Yes, edited the challenge.

Comment: Can the input be taken as an array? e.g. `["_","\n",...]`

Comment: @oeuf sure, Mr Egg.

Comment: May we have a trailing newline in the input? For example, `" _ \n|_|\n"` for input #1.

Comment: Can the input be a two-dimensional array, i.e. all lines right-padded with spaces so they have the same length?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
Ç°·üö7%J»232¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPuhDYe2H95zeJu5qteh3UbGRocW/f8fraQQrwBG8SCkoKSjoFQTXwPkg3F8TY1SLAA)

## Explanation

```
Ç          convert each character to its ASCII code
°          map each number to 10**x
·          times two
üö         for each consecutive pair of rows, convert the number as a number in 
           a base of the next number
7%         modulo 7
J          join each row into a string of numbers
»          join the rows together with a newline
232        push the string "232" (pushing it as a compressed number doesn't work due to a bug)
¢          and count how many times it appears in the string of digits
```

| Characters | ASCII codes | 2 * 10^first number converted from base-2*10^second number, mod 7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 32, 32 | 4 |
| `_` | 32, 95 | 4 |
| `|` | 32, 124 | 2 |
| `_` | 95, 32 | 4 |
| `_` `_` | 95, 95 | 3 |
| `_` `|` | 95, 124 | 2 |
| `|` | 124, 32 | 1 |
| `|` `_` | 124, 95 | 1 |
| `|` `|` | 124, 124 | 2 |

Comment: Pretty annoying that [this bug](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/issues/164) still hasn't been fixed and that `§` is necessary here. :/ But nice approach regardless!

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 23 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes character matrix as argument.

```apl
≢∘⍸{'_||_'≡2↓,¯1⌽⍵}⌺2 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HnokcdMx717qhWj6@piVd/1LnQ6FHbZJ1D6w0f9ex91Lu19lHPLiMF4/9pj9omPOrte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDAapmQjWNQ@IuBTiuWria7hQBePjsYliEVKIVwCjeAWIDiATjIGuRFUJMwJiHYTAVAKWVsAvDdEdj11aAaYVTAIA)

`{`…`}⌺2 3` on each 2-by-3 submatrix:
   `_` 
  `|_|`

`¯1⌽⍵` rotate the columns cyclically one step to the left
    `_`
  `||_`

`,` ravel (flatten)
    `_||_`

`2↓` drop the first two elements
  `_||_`

`'_||_'≡` does the string match?

`≢∘⍸` count the **i**ndices where true

Comment: @Fatalize Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(c+a[n+a.find('\n'):][:3]=='_|_|'for n,c in enumerate(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xbsMgEIZ3P8VtBqXyko3KY7p2yeZYJ@IcCq19RgSrjeR3dzEkVlQJxPH9H9y5e7iOvF9MfVp6PZwvGrS6TYPodrrhna6M5YsoT1xK1TZq39Z1iTPOpRk98FsHloF4GsjrQEJLuVh2UEPTFj9X2xMc/USqAAj@vh4AvWWKQtSmIGRC1iSqVlhp5yi2XEFOqb/FyHnLQZg0SvU1WhZRllK@w9Ywqr8duQCHz4@D96PPDc@e9PcCCEWcuygQMRcxehQIaeG6EouXtHGeIecJ5y/whcHG/mv41Dbh@fQP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.unicode`, 66 bytes

```factor
[| s | "_"s "|_|"s [ start-all* ] 2bi@ 10 s index v-n ∩ length ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fU69SgNBEMb23kH4uFK4Q61Em2AjNjZilYRlvUzM4Wbu3J0LEdfed7C5JoKPpKVP4t5tNIaAwwwz8_0M8_o21YVUtv3c27-5vry6OMU9WSYDRw8NcUEOpiq0cRsgp6VY7TDXMssX1NnXS8NlUU0ItSWRx9qWLDhLkqcEIVIojNgrP-I0AkqpbSDOvbJP1WU0ha0v5TfyThPZ9WW1y-Ef7sentrk_hl_f86qRaXbycT70cPDh99T1_4Y2hBNtJdPGHGCM49tygKPDICt5QkssMsbXyzsM8Z3MMI6XVnNdI49z28b-DQ)

Input is a multiline string padded with spaces so each line is the same length. This answer relies on there being a trailing newline in the input; if that is not allowed, let me know and I will change my answer.

It finds the starting indices of (possibly overlapping) subsequences `"_"` and `"|_|"`, subtracts the index of the first newline from the `"|_|"` indices, takes the intersection between the two sequences of indices, and returns the length of that.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€ü3øεü2ε€ÁJ„_|ºÅ¿]˜O
```

Input as a right-padded list of lines.

-1 byte using the rotate approach from [*@Adám*'s APL (Dyalog Unicode) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250114/52210)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaw3uMD@84t/XwHqNzW0HcRq9HDfPiaw7tOtx6aH/s6Tn@//9HKynEKygoKOko1cTXxEPo@PgapVgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpeRfWgLh2VfqOSn9f9S05vAe48M7zm09vMfo3FYQt9HrUcO8@JpDuw63Htofe3qO/38lvTCdQ9s47f9HKynEK8Tk1cTXKOkoKMXHx8PZCgoIcaAaMIoHIYgwkAfG8TVwFRAJqHHxKMIK2IVhquPhwnBlMNWxAA).

`€ÁJ„_|ºÅ¿]˜O` could alternatively be `ćÅs«]˜„|_2×¢` for the same byte-count:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaw3uMD@84t/XwHqNzW4@0H24tPrQ69vScRw3zauKNDk8/tOj//2glhXgFBQUlHaWa@Jp4CB0fX6MUCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpeRfWgLh2VfqOSn9f9S05vAe48M7zm09vMfo3NYj7Ydbiw@tjj0951HDvJp4o8PTDy36r6QXpnNoG6f9/2glhXiFmLya@BolHQWl@Ph4OFtBASEOVANG8SAEEQbywDi@Bq4CIgE1Lh5FWAG7MEx1PFwYrgymOhYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
€                 # Map over each inner string of the (implicit) input-list:
 ü3               #  Create overlapping triplets
   ø              # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    ε             # Map over each inner list:
     ü2           #  Create overlapping pairs
       ε          #  Map over each pair of strings:
        €         #   Map over each string:
         Á        #    Rotate its characters once towards the right
          J       #   Join the two strings together
           „_|    #   Push string "_|"
              º   #   Mirror it to "_||_"
               Å¿ #   Check if the string ends with "_||_"
    ]             # Close the nested maps
     ˜            # Flatten the list of pairs
      O           # Sum
                  # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
        ć         #   Extract head ([a,b] to [b] and a with `a` on top)
         Ås       #   Pop this head, and leave just its middle character
           «      #   Append it to the string in the remainder-list
    ]             # Close the nested maps
     ˜            # Flatten the list of list of wrapped strings
      „|_         # Push string "|_"
         2×       # Double it to "|_|_"
           ¢      # Count how many "|_|_" are in the list
                  # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 37 bytes

```
&`(?<=(.)*)._.*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)^)\|_\|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy5DYAwDEV7T@EG5KAQiZ5jEcSHgoKGAlF6LgZgsRCSUCDZ//CTfKznti/@vsiStRS8kPl1X84ytJ04UxkHV91XqHXThy6DNGYyo2JU7xmkUCIgB2bOARwHnFCIcaERvqckufK/Jor86UNRHw) Link is to test suite that takes double-spaced test cases. Explanation: The lookbehind calculates the column that the left `|` should be in, then the arbitrary character above it is matched, then a `_`, then a .NET balancing group is used to advance the match to the corresponding column on the next line, then then `|_|` is matched. The `&` stage modifier is used to allow the matches to overlap.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code, 31 bytes

```
31 F6 6A FF 59 B0 0A F2 AE AE 8B 57 FD 8A 14 0F 81 FA 5F 7C 5F 7C 75 02 FF C6 AE 76 ED 96 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNb6MwED17fsUsqwhoSNUvVSuS7KXnXnpaKYksYgy4AoMw2XUU8teXDpCkzaGSMZ55b94bxoiqmqVCdF1kCvTwzfHgNs3LbZRjAknIbFmjNCroN2DVzmQ4u59jVVZYCwusKP9ilAforrULrJaVlmhEZLbAxlcdDhwZ2wBXdaxmj5uxKs7HxJR0KCWKaiS53MUW3dZdLH71B06H@@dz6uEJ2HvvAUxpMXRlwpMVe99KrIFZkaWnpiPbN9WA76A/B2kbWWt0Xhw8KN1g4olSmwZFFtV4Y/z5EeAnyea7WOLCNLEqb7PfAF9ZjTQNuUmz2uASDzQw5Agtb8kjAAo5519DxCuUyMPi/RoQCoaHtyPpzBrAUfq6nFL4HXCq4FfAhftZcZxDP4AiUtrz4QAsoXu@mkaDIV6@1QdGHFbVVJR4zkSttRPQ@BqfpsqOcEHW@jUSmaILEmUsQ6eHeyNLs7oLcE9hXOLhTMfJ3cMfUtovPW@njUq1jAf/Gz/xV3Y63dCd4L9M5RK9Pf4gEfvy2IteFLyJwu2eOvWHniyBx677L5I8Sk03K56faKOfe0l8mX8A)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the address of a null-terminated byte string in RDI, and returns the number of cells in EAX. This requires the lines to be padded to the same length.

In assembly:

```
f:  xor esi, esi        # Set ESI to 0. ESI will count the cells.
    push -1; pop rcx    # Set RCX to -1.
    mov al, '\n'        # Set AL to the ASCII code of the line feed.
    repne scasb         # Repeatedly compare AL with a byte from the string,
                        #  advancing the pointer each time, until they match.
                        #  Also count down RCX each time.  This consumes the first line
                        #  and makes RCX -(linelength+1), with linelength including \n.
    scasb               # Make one more comparison, advancing RDI once more.
r:  mov edx, [rdi-3]    # Load bytes from addresses RDI-3 to RDI into EDX.
    mov dl, [rdi+rcx]   # Replace the first of those bytes with one at address RDI+RCX,
                        #  the position in the previous line above the third byte.
    cmp edx, '_' | '|'<<8 | '_'<<16 | '|'<<24   # Compare EDX with the cell's bytes.
    jne s               # Jump to skip if they are not equal.
    inc esi             # (If equal) Add 1 to ESI.
s:  scasb               # Compare AL with a byte from the string; advance the pointer.
    jbe r               # Jump back, to repeat, if AL ≤ that byte (false only for 0).
    xchg esi, eax       # Switch the total from ESI into EAX.
    ret                 # Return.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
C6+¨pe11%ṅ⁋3l⁺↔SO
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJDNivCqHBlMTEl4bmF4oGLM2zigbrihpRTTyIsIiIsIltcIiBfIF8gXCIsIFwifF98X3xcIiwgXCJ8X3xffFwiXSJd) or [verify test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiQzYrwqhwZTExJeG5heKBizNs4oG64oaUU08iLCIiLCJbXCIgXyBcIixcInxffFwiXVxuW1wiX19fXCIsXCJ8X3xcIl1cbltcIiAgIFwiLFwifF98XCJdXG5bXCIgXyAgXyAgX18gX18gIFwiLFwifF98ICBffCAgX3xffHxcIl1cbltcIiBfICAgXCIsXCJ8X3xfIFwiLFwifF98X3xcIl1cbltcIiBfICAgXCIsXCJ8IHxfIFwiLFwifF98X3xcIl1cbltcIiBfICAgXCIsXCJ8X3xfIFwiLFwifF9fX3xcIl1cbltcIiBfIF8gXCIsXCJ8X3xffFwiLFwifF98X3xcIl0iXQ==).

-2 bytes thanks to Command Master

Comment: another approach I found which might work better in Vyxal - \$ (6+a)^{6+b} \mod 11 \$ with a, b char codes, and then you look for `121`

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 30 bytes

```
[:+/@,2 3('._.\|_\|'rxE,);._3]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxL9pKW99Bx0jBWENdL14vpiY-pka9qMJVR9NaL944FqLo5gdNLj8nPQUktZhKMVTUxNeo61oZKhgrmCiYVsNUpSZn5CukKcQCeUYKsSAnGXApxCuAUTwQcQG1AZlgHF9Tw6XJhUMLSCGEqFEgrCoeryqouhooqakA8feCBRAaAA)

*+1 thanks to Neil for spotting a subtle bug*

- `2 3...;._3]` Looks at all 2 x 3 squares
- `('._.\|_\|'rxE,)` Checks if the flatten regex matches the required pattern
- `[:+/@,` Sums the matches

Comment: You need a leading `.` in your regex otherwise it will match `__|`/`_||`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->l{a,*l=l;g=0;l.sum{|b|w=a.chars.count{"#{b[g,3]}#{a[g+=1]}"=="|_|_"};a=b;w}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoMwEADAr8h6s2mweAzrR0IIG8F4SFW0IZTNvj2lc50rh29bsT3nxKSGhMlEHE3Sd35zDbUg6WWj69bLkfcPQ8/BRjU56ZlsfODLCSBC9dWDGMJgikg7u9Va6Dyo/4Bz7Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 54 bytes

```
2`xp"`,*3`xp \; `'"`', \+ `/
`,* `flat `_`"._.\|_\|"?t
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin) Takes a list of equal-sized space-padded strings.

For testing purposes, the code below auto-converts a space-padded multiline string:

```
\@..
 _  _  __ __  
|_|  _|  _|_||
@ >ls ; outln
2`xp"`,*3`xp \; `'"`', \+ `/
`,* `flat `_`"._.\|_\|"?t
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
2`xp ( `,* 3`xp \; `' ) `', \+ `/
`,* `flat `_` "._.\|_\|"?t
```

- `` 2`xp (...) `', `` pairwise flatmap...

  - `` `,* 3`xp \; `' `` zip and triplet-wise map...

    - `` `,* `flat `_` `` zip, flatten, convert to string
    - `"._.\|_\|"?t` check if matches regex `/._.\|_\|/`
- `` \+ `/ `` sum

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
Ji6\^[aJa;0J0]_Z+4=z
```

Input is a 2-dimensional char array (rows should be righty-padded with spaces so that they have the same length).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yvTLCYuOtEr0drAyyA2PkrbxLbq//9o9fj4eHVrBfWa@Br1WAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N8r0ywmLjrRK9HawMsgNj5K28S26r97srqCelJlhEtURcj/aHWFeAUFdWsF9Zr4GgX1WK5o9fj4eFQBIANMg1SCUDwIwZUoQHB8DUIRTA5uTjy6nAIeOYQ@BYQcsnKEPgA) (this displays each input together with output, for convenience).

#### How it works

Modulo 6 is applied to (the ASCII code of) the chars in the input, which gives `5` for `_`, `4` for `|` and `2` for  . Element-wise exponentiation with the imaginary unit `j` respectively gives `j`, `1` and `-1`.

Two-dimensional convolution is then used to detect the desired pattern, using the matrix `[-1, j, -1; 0, j, 0]` as kernel (note that convolution flips the kernel in both directions). The pattern is detected whenever the convolution gives exactly `4`. Thus the final result is the number of times that `4` appears in the convolution output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＩΣＥυ∧κＬΦ⌕Ａι|_|⁼_§§υ⊖κ⊕λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsIwEITvfYolpw3EJ@ip@AMFhUIfIIR2McF0rWmiHvruMYI/e5iBmdlvsCYMV@NzfljnCbDlOcU@BsdnlBK6tFhMCpysq66EEbdmidinCU9mfjcNj3hRcCQ@R4sH5yOFYjw23qNTIFa9Cqlgf0vGLyi0KD@x5ZGe@PWC2dEQaCKOVHCy7Fv@B17@rs4ZNOiqUPX60by5@xc) Link is to verbose version of code. Assumes input is a rectangular list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the strings into an array.

```
   υ                      Array of strings
  Ｅ                       Map over strings
     κ                    Current index
    ∧                     Logical And
        ⌕Ａ                All overlapping matches of
           |_|            Literal string `|_|`
          ι               In current string
       Φ                  Filtered where
                  υ       Array of strings
                 §        Indexed by
                    κ     Outer index
                   ⊖      Decremented
                §         Indexed by
                      λ   Current match position
                     ⊕    Incremented
              ⁼           Is equal to
               _          Literal string `_`
      Ｌ                   Take the length
 Σ                        Take the sum
Ｉ                         Cast to string
                          Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), 23 bytes

```
≢∘⍸1↓'|_|'∘⍷∧¯1⊖1⌽'_'∘=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8GCpaUlaboWtxiD0h61TXjUuehRx4xHvTsMH7VNVq-Jr1EHc7c_6lh-aL3ho65pho969qrHg0RtuR71TQVqSYNQRgrGCo96t6grxCuAtGGXjI-Pxy2poIBVp6EJ1FgwigchkDogG4zja9C1GCuYwlwCVgl2EIbBqKoUiFIFMSsenyqoMRCzIEELDWFYSAMA)

This is an alternative to [Adám’s ⌺-based solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250114) that is exactly as long but quite a bit faster:

```
      f←≢∘⍸{'_||_'≡2↓,¯1⌽⍵}⌺2 3
      g←≢∘⍸1↓'|_|'∘⍷∧¯1⊖1⌽'_'∘=
      m←(,⍨1e3)⍴' _|'[?1e6⍴3]
      'cmpx'⎕CY'dfns'
      cmpx'f m' 'g m'
  f m → 2.1E0  |    0% ⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕
  g m → 4.0E¯3 | -100%
```

The basic idea is to find where the top parts (`_`) and the bottom parts (`|_|`) of the squares are, align them, and count how many times they overlap.

We’ll use a modified version of the fifth test case as an example:

```
      ⎕←m←3 5⍴'__|_||_|_ |_|_|'
__|_|
|_|_ 
|_|_|
```

First we find where the `|_|`s are:

```
      ('|_|'∘⍷)m
0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
```

The 1s indicate where the `|_|`s begin. This means that the rightmost two columns will always consist of 0s.

Then we find where the `_`s are:

```
      ('_'∘=)m
1 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0
```

We need to move the 1s one step to the left and one step downwards to align them with the 1s in the `|_|` matrix, then AND the two matrices.

We can move the 1s one step to the left by rotating once along the last axis:

```
      (1⌽'_'∘=)m
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
```

The leftmost column wraps around to the right, creating an extra 1 in the rightmost column. Fortunately, this doesn’t matter because the corresponding column in the `|_|` matrix must consist of 0s, so this column will get masked out anyway.

Next we move the 1s one step downwards by doing a -1 rotate along the first axis:

```
      (¯1⊖1⌽'_'∘=)m
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
```

Now the 1s are aligned, but the bottommost row wraps around to the top, creating extra 1s in the topmost row. This is a problem because the corresponding row in the `|_|` matrix can contain 1s. We can fix this by dropping the topmost row after ANDing the two matrices:

```
      ('|_|'∘⍷∧¯1⊖1⌽'_'∘=)m
0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
      (1↓'|_|'∘⍷∧¯1⊖1⌽'_'∘=)m
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
```

Finally, we count the number of 1s:

```
      (≢∘⍸1↓'|_|'∘⍷∧¯1⊖1⌽'_'∘=)m
3
```